# Merging Multiple AWS developer accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working for two separate employers, on a project with similar goals. Both use Amazon EC2 for their servers, and both gave me an account to access their instances, with different userid and password pair, is it possible to have these 2 accounts be a subset of another account? So i can switch easily from one account to another from that main account?

Comment: Maybe it is possible with `sts:AssumeRole`? I am still learning, but I found some interesting blog posts: [How Do I Protect Cross-Account Access Using MFA?](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxIH1XOX2OOJKI/How-do-I-protect-cross-account-access-using-MFA) (February 2014) and [New – Cross-Account Access in the AWS Management Console](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-account-access-in-the-aws-management-console/) (January 2015)

Answer (score 1):

No, not unless you want the superset account to also assume billing responsibility for the sub-accounts. I'm pretty sure neither you nor either of your two employers would appreciate being billed for the composite EC2 usage of both...

From a working-practices viewpoint, however, you can configure [ElasticFox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/elasticfox/) with any number of different account configurations and switch between them at the click of a dropdown.

Comment: okay. i was thinking that both of the accounts are exclusive of each other, but i have a 'manager' account. thanks for the answer

Comment: I think billing responsibility is not related to how AWS accounts can be accessed. Quote from [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidatedbilling-when.html): _Consolidated Billing is strictly an accounting and billing feature. It is not a method for controlling accounts, or provisioning resources for accounts. It doesn't change how the accounts function or how they are accessed._

Comment: You do realise that this answer is heading towards three years old and AWS have changed much of their multi-account functionality since I wrote it, right?

Comment: Yes, probably there have been a lot of changes in AWS since the answer was written. Of course the answer was written to reflect the situation at the time it was written. In my first comment I could have added "Maybe things have changed ..." to make that clear.